# How to measure interference between processes

Tags: performance, computer-science, performance-testing, measurement, perf

In parallel systems every process has an impact onto other processes, because they all compete for several scarce resources like cpu-caches, memory, disk I/O, network, etc.

What method is best suited for measuring interference between processes? Such as Process A & B each access the disk heavily. So running them parallel will probably slower then running sequential (individual runtime). Because the bottleneck is the hard drive.

If I don't know exactly the behaviour of a process (disk-, memory- or cpu- intensive), what method would be best to analyse that?

Measure individual runtime and compare the relative share of each parallel process?

Like process A runs on average 30s alone, when 100% parallel with B 45s, when 20% parallel 35s.. etc ??

Would it be better to compare several indicators like L1 & LLC cache misses, page faults, etc.??

Comment: is this platform agnostic question? if target is windows platform, I guess it does provide individual disk utilization metrics. That's how 'resource monitor' can plot graph of disk activity per process level.

Comment: You can measure it, just observe consumed time.  But the measurement is pretty useless, it will repeat very, very poorly.

Comment: @Ankush the primary platform is Linux

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is first determine what the limiting factors are on each of the individual programs.  If you want to run CPU-bound and IO-bound at the same time it'll have very little impact.  If you want to run two IO-bound processes and the same time there'll be a lot of contention.

I wrote a rather detailed answer about how to interpret the output of "time [command]" results to see what's the limiting factor.  It's here:  [What caused my elapsed time much longer than user time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688840/what-caused-my-elapsed-time-much-longer-than-user-time/13752849#13752849)

Once you have the ouput from "time"ing your programs you can determine which are likely to step on one another and which are not.